# Rocket like movement in cocos 2d V3 with chipmunk

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

On tapping on screen I`m gonna apply impulse and angular rotation to sprite to move it to the sides.  But after some time OR parameters of physics body attached to sprite should go back to initial (impulse 0, angular speed = 0). What are the best ways to do that (use CCAction or on update detect parameters of physics body and change them to initial)?

Comment: define "best" otherwise the answer is: "any way that works is fine"

Answer (score 0):

If i were in your position, I would probably start a timer at the first collision of the sprite and then use a CCAction to transition to the initial state to make it look smooth. Don't know if its the best way though.

Comment: Currently I`ve made next: On clicking on screen I`m applying impulse to specific side (left or right) and in update method I`m applying force in opposite direction, if velocity of body change its sign (due to applied force it would move to another direction) I`m changing force value and velocity to 0. But for now getting some bug, body is not stopping although, velocity is not equal to 0

Comment: There is demo for chipmunk with Orbital Movement example https://github.com/slembcke/Chipmunk2D/blob/master/Demo/Planet.c